# Get attribute from the clicked Object JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm newbie with javascript and bad English either .

1)I have HTML like this:

```
<ul id="search-list" class="playlist1"> 
   <li class="song songW" data-song-id="70"> 
      <div id="songNum" class="songNum" songurl="music/turn-it-up.mp3"
         songtitle="Turn It Up">Turn It Up
      </div>  
   </li>


   <li class="song songB" data-song-id="83">   
       <div id="songNum" class="songNum" songurl="music/black-keys.mp3"     
          songtitle="Black Keys">Black Keys </div>  
   </li>
 </ul>
```

2) I use this Javascript to get attribute from the clicked DIV have class or id = "songNum" :

```
 var el = $("ul#search-list");
 $(el).bind(".songNum").click(function(eve) {                   
      eve.preventDefault();          
      songUrl = $(this).attr("songurl");
      alert(songUrl);});        
  ///// It's return "Undefined"
```

3) And when i change

```
 var el = $("ul#search-list");
 $(el).bind(".songNum").click(function(eve) {                   
      eve.preventDefault();          
      songUrl = $(".songNum").attr("songurl");
      alert(songUrl);   }); 
 ///// It's just return a atrribute of the first DIV =>"music/turn-it-up.mp3", even i was click on the second DIV
```

Please help me, show me my mistake !
Thanks alots !!!

Comment: You're clearly using some library (that use of the `$` function). What library? The usual suspect would be jQuery, but that's not how you use jQuery... Doesn't look like Prototype or MooTools, either.

Comment: What does console.log(this) return in the .song click event handler?

Comment: There are more <li> behind, i dont' use ID for check Click, i use Class :(

Answer (score 0):

```
 var el = $("ul#search-list li");
 $(el).bind(".song").click(function(eve) {                  
      eve.preventDefault();          
      songUrl = $(this).find('div').attr("songurl");
      alert(songUrl);
});
```

should work. Use `$(this)` to have the context of the first div which is clicked, than find the child div inside and then you could access its properties.

Hope that helped

Comment: It's return exactly like i use $(".songNum").attr("songurl"); It's return only a first DIV :(, when i click on the second or the third div, the attribute value only return the value of first DIV :(

Comment: My bad. I've edited my answer. Look at `$el` I've added li in order to work. You binded only the ul elem, but we wanted to bind every li elem inside ul.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but...the code not run anymore :(

var songUrl ;        
 var el = $("ul#search-list li");
  $(el).bind(".song").click(function(eve) {
     eve.preventDefault();    
   
           songUrl = $(this).find('div').attr("songurl");
   alert(songUrl);
});

Comment: I Change my solution  to :

    $(document).ready(function(){

    $("img.anhien").click(function(){
    songUrl = $(this).attr("songurl");
    alert(songUrl);
    }

    });
But the code not run, am i wrong somewhere ?

Comment: Have a look here at this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7FbJb/ it is perfectly working with my code above no ?